# Problem enabling 3d acceleration in virt-manager

Tags: virt-manager

I am using MX Linux and i have problem enabling 3d acceleration in virt-manager. I enable 3d acceleration by checking OpenGL box in `Display Spice` section and then selecting `Virtio` in `Video` section, but after that if i try to start the virtual machine i get this error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 72, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 108, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/libvirtobject.py", line 57, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/object/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1373, in create
    raise libvirtError('virDomainCreate() failed')
libvirt.libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor
```

I found that if i change 'user' and 'group' from 'libvirt-qemu' to 'root' in /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf i don't get this error when starting virtual machine, but i see only black screen when the machine starts.